# Does water have properties suggesting it has a phase transition at 50-63 Celsius so it has two phases?

Tags: water, phase

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsQXN-Kh2-w&t=497s

In this video, he says that water has four properties (surface tension, refractive index... ) that transition from 50 - 63 Celsius between totally separate values? Eminently testable but I don't have the facilities. I tried searching but there some statements of liquid water having two phases but related to supercooled water. What experimental evidence is there that  water has 2 phases and a transition occurs at 50C?

Comment: Sounds like nonsense.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, The video is non-sense, but the report in *Science* on the two states of *supercooled* water is not. The video is apparently made on this paper. The title of the paper "Experimental observation of the liquid-liquid transition in bulk supercooled water under pressure." There are no two phases like hexane and water mixtures, but some transitions were observed at nano to microsecond timescales.